# Foreign keys, relationship between models in sqlalchemy flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I have these two models:

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('id',),
    )

    id       = db.Column(db.Integer, primarky_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email    = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)


class Review(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'reviews'
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', ),
    )
    id        = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content   = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

I wanted to create a relationship between these two tables so that when a user writes a review it should go to Review model and it has a relation with `user_id` in Users model. I have tried lots of answers but they are returning different kinds of errors I am confused, can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `db.relationship` to create a one-to-many relationship between users and reviews.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('id',),
    )

    id       = db.Column(db.Integer, primarky_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email    = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    reviews = db.relationship('Review', backref='user', cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan')


class Review(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'reviews'
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', ),
    )
    id        = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content   = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
```

This would allow for `user.reviews` and `review.user`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
user = db.relationship(User, backref='user_reviews', lazy=True)`

And read the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationships.html).